# Parallax scroling element does not want to listen me

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a nice parallax scrolling site, and this is my first time to do something as this. 
Here is part of my code.

```
<header>
        <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="section1">
                    <!--<img src="images/Untitled-1.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section2">
                <div class="coveculjak" id="eboy">
                    <div class="coveculjak2">

                    </div>  
                </div>          
                <!--<img src="images/dobrodosli.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" width="100%">-->
            </div>              



        </header>
        <body>


            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="section3">
                </div>
            </div>

         <div class="kontakt">
                <div class="well well-sm">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend class="text-center header">Contact us</legend>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i></span>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <input id="fname" name="name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i></span>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <input id="lname" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o bigicon"></i></span>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-phone-square bigicon"></i></span>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o bigicon"></i></span>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Unesite vašu poruku i u najskorijem roku ćemo Vas kontaktirati." rows="7"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg dugme">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1600px){
body,
html {
margin:0;
padding:0;
width: 80%;
height: auto;
}
.section1 {
max-width: 80%;
}
.section2 {
max-width:100%;
background-size: 1600px 642px;

}
.section3 {
max-width:100%;
background-size: 1600px 200px;
}
.coveculjak {
width: 700px;
margin-left: 380px;
}
}

* { margin:0; padding:0; } /* to remove the top and left whitespace */


body,
html {
margin:0;
padding:0;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
.container-fluid{
width: 100%;
height: auto;

}       
.section1 {
max-width: 100%;
padding:0;
margin:0;
height:auto;

position: relative;
height: 800px;  
background-image: url("../images/head.png");
size: auto 600px;
position: top-center;
background-attachment: fixed;
overflow: hidden;

}
.section1 img {
width:100%;
height:auto;


}
.coveculjak {
width: 900px;
height: 300px;
background-image: url("../images/eboy.png"); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: bottom;
position: absolute;

margin-top: 5%;
margin-left: 28%;


}


.section2 {
width:100%;
padding:0;
margin:0;
height:auto;
position: relative;
height: 646px;  
background-image: url("../images/dobrodosli01.png");

size: contain;
position: top-center;
z-index: -100;


}
.section2  img {
width:100%;
height:auto;

}
.kontakt {
    margin-top:280px;
    position: relative;
    position: top-center;
background-attachment: fixed;
overflow: hidden;
opacity: 0.2;

}
.section3 {
height:200px;
background-image: url("../images/kapija.png");
z-index: 100;

 }
.section3 img{
position: relative;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: 100;

}
.section4 {
margin-bottom: 20px;
position: relative;
opacity: 0;
transform: translateX(-40px);
}
.is-showing{
opacity: 1;
transform: translateX(0px);
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.is-hide {
opacity: 0;
position: relative;

}
```

JS

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();


if($(window).scrollTop() > 750){

    //$(".coveculjak").css({"transform" :  "translate(0px, "+ 1.1 +"px)"});
    $(".coveculjak").css({"transform" :  "translateY(0px)"});
    $(".coveculjak").css("margin-top", wScroll-600+"px");

}

else{
     $('.coveculjak').css({
  'transform' : 'translate(3px, '+ wScroll /12 +'%)'});

     $(".coveculjak").css("margin-top", "0px");
     $(".coveculjak").css("margin-left", wScroll/ 1.5);
    // $(".coveculjak").css({"transform" : "translateX(200px)"});
    // $(".coveculjak").css({"margin-left", wScroll-300+"px"});        
}

if (wScroll > $('.section4').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 2.2)) { // umesto .offset().top - 500
    //                  Vidi visunu ekrana i podeli je sa ... da ne bi bilo fiksno! Razmotriti i 1,8 i 2.2 vrednost! 
    $('.section4').each(function(i){

        setTimeout(function(){

            $('.section4').eq(i).addClass('is-showing');
        }, 250 * (i+1));
        });             
    // malo me mozda buni eq= equal?    
 }
  var kontaktOffset = $('.kontakt').offset().top - 100;

 //alert(kontaktOffset);
 if (wScroll > kontaktOffset - ($(window).height() / 200 )) {


     $('.coveculjak').css({
  'transform' : 'translate(200px' + wScroll / 120 + '%)'});

     $(".coveculjak").css("margin-top", kontaktOffset - 800 +"px");
     $(".coveculjak").css("margin-left", wScroll / 120);
    // $(".kontakt").css("z-index", -100);
    //$('.coveculjak').css({'transform' : 'translate(3px, ' + wScroll / 12 + '%)'});
    //$(".coveculjak").css("margin-top", "0px");
    // $(".coveculjak").css("margin-left", wScroll - 300 "px");
}
```

So I am stuck with 2 things.

1. My boy who is scrolling on the page, should slide from right to the left when he comes to the contact section. As he does it on the top of the page, only opposite.
   But in this case he just disappear and  appear to other coordinate.
2. And oher problem is that I am working now on my PC, when I test it on the laptop it doe's not look as I want, The boy is sliding too long, so how can and if I reduce value in JS code, than it is good on laptop but not in PC...
   **$(".coveculjak").css("margin-left", wScroll/ 1.5);** So can I use some percentage or do sometjing else?

I hope that you can understand what I want to ask, and hope to this question is properly.

Comment: Can you maybe put your code into a JSFiddle so we can test it more easily?

Comment: @PascalGoldbach https://jsfiddle.net/PoznanM/w9tnagag/ 
Sry I forgot to put it into post! Thnx